# Make a function happen while echoing some text if a certain string matches in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, preg-match

I have an array element that contains a subpage's content:
**$page['content']**

I want to do some MySQL query, if the variable's content contains this pattern: **{gallery:somerandomIDnumber}**

The problem is, I don't want to lose the other stuff, and it's also important that the query should run where the pattern belongs.

**For example, this is the $page['content'] content:**

```
<h1>Title of the page</h1>
{gallery:10}
<p>Other informations...</p>
```

I tried this with preg_match function, but unfortunately I can't figure it out, how I can save the other content around my {gallery:10} pattern.

```
// Gallery include by ID
preg_match('~\{gallery\:[0-9]{1,5}\}~', $page['content'], $matches);

    foreach($matches[0] as $value) {
        $int = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $query  = 'SELECT * ';
        $query .= 'FROM gallery_images ';
        $query .= 'WHERE gid = '.$int;
        $gallery = ms_query($query); //ms_query is a function I wrote myself. Unlike mysqli_query function this function doesn't require the connection parameter every single time I call it, only the query itself

        while($gimage = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gallery)) {
            echo '<img src="admin/uploaded/'.$gimage['imagepath'].'" width ="100">'; 
        }
    }
```

**Summarazing, in this situation, I want to echo**

1. the title of the page
2. some imagepath from my database
3. other informations

Thanks in return for Your help!

Answer (score 0):

preg match will get you something in $matches only when u put it in ().
e.g. in your {gallery:10}
you will get the 10 if you make your preg like this;

preg_match('~{gallery:([0-9]{1,5})}~', $page['content'], $matches);

also echo your sql query and paste result